# JS - extract an Array property from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Code:

```
var obj = {val1: 'Test',val2: 'Test','array[]': [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' ] };

console.log(obj.array);
```

Issue: the above console.log returns undefined. For many, it might be obvious, but I'm a newb and trying to figure out how to log the array[] (it works if the property is simply defined as {'array': ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]}).

Expected output: ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406)

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
console.log(obj['array[]']);
```

The property you are trying to access is called `array[]`, not `array`.

You'll have to use square bracket notation to access the property (i.e. `obj['array[]']` and not `obj.array[]`) because the property name is not a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1):

the object property is named `array[]`, not `array`. Rename it to `array` and you will get the results you are expecting.

```js
var obj = {val1: 'Test',val2: 'Test','array': [ '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' ] };

console.log(obj.array);
```

Comment: The above is just an example of the end result of the object. its definition is 
let obj : {val1:any; val2:any; array:any[];} it names it like that (not user defined). Thanks for your feedback though.